# After typing sudo apt update its comes bunch of error like 404 not found

Tags: software-installation

[its says Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.garr.it/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found]

Comment: That mirror only supports amd64, i386 as far as I can see - http://ubuntu.mirror.garr.it/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/   Not all mirrors provide ports (eg. armhf, arm64 etc)

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu installation is correct. This is a 404. `/binary-armhf` [does not exist in that mirror](http://ubuntu.mirror.garr.it/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/):

[image: In the Repo]

I would suggest removing that repo from your `apt` sources file unless it contains something you need to keep up to date.